# Staircase problem: How to print the combinations?

Tags: java, depth-first-search, backtracking

Question:

> In this problem, the scenario we are evaluating is the following: You're standing at the base of a staircase and are heading to the top. A small stride will move up one stair, and a large stride advances two. You want to count the number of ways to climb the entire staircase based on different combinations of large and small strides. For example, a staircase of three steps can be climbed in three different ways: three small strides, one small stride followed by one large stride, or one large followed by one small.

The call of waysToClimb(3) should produce the following output:

```
1 1 1,
1 2,
2 1
```

My code:

```
public static void waysToClimb(int n){
    if(n == 0) 
        System.out.print("");
    else if(n == 1)
        System.out.print("1");
    else {
        System.out.print("1 "); 
        waysToClimb(n - 1);
        System.out.print(",");
        System.out.print("2 ");
        waysToClimb(n - 2);
    }
}
```

My output:

```
1 1 1,
2,
2 1
```

My recursion doesn't seem to remember the path it took any idea how to fix it?

Edit:

Thank you guys for the responses. Sorry for the late reply

I figured it out

```
public static void waysToClimb(int n){

    String s ="[";
    int p=0;
    com(s,p,n);

}

public static void com(String s,int p,int n){

    if(n==0 && p==2)

    System.out.print(s.substring(0,s.length()-2)+"]");

    else if(n==0 && p !=0)

    System.out.print(s+"");

    else if(n==0 && p==0)

    System.out.print("");

    else if(n==1)

    System.out.print(s+"1]");

    else {

        com(s+"1, ",1,n-1);
        System.out.println();
        com(s+"2, ",2,n-2);

    }

}
```

Comment: The question states that you should count the number of different ways, not print them. Which one is it that is the expected output?

Comment: you don't count(summ up the number of steps) -   every call of the waysToClimb adds 1 to the amount of posible steps unless you have 0 steps left. where you put the increment is just a decission you have to make(you only have to take care that you don't count twice).

Comment: Beware the answers below don't cover the core of the problem really well (either looping semantics or there's also a mathematical solution if you're aware)

Answer (score 1):

If you explicity want to print all paths (different than counting them or finding a specific one), you need to store them all the way down to 0.

```
public static void waysToClimb(int n, List<Integer> path)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        //  print whole path
        for (Integer i: path)
        {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    else if (n == 1)
    {
        List<Integer> newPath = new ArrayList<Integer>(path);
        newPath.add(1);
        waysToClimb(n-1, newPath);
    }
    else if (n > 1)
    {
        List<Integer> newPath1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(path);
        newPath1.add(1);
        waysToClimb(n-1, newPath1);

        List<Integer> newPath2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(path);
        newPath2.add(2);
        waysToClimb(n-2, newPath2);
    }
}
```

initial call: `waysToClimb(5, new ArrayList<Integer>());`

Answer (score 0):

Below mentioned solution will work similar to Depth First Search, it will explore one path. Once a path is completed, it will backtrace and explore other paths:

```
public class Demo {
    private static LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>(){{ add(1);add(2);}};

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        waysToClimb(4, "");
    }

    public static void waysToClimb(int n, String res) {
        if (ll.peek() > n)
            System.out.println(res);
        else {
            for (Integer elem : ll) {
                if(n-elem >= 0)
                    waysToClimb(n - elem, res + String.valueOf(elem) + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test2 {

    public int climbStairs(int n) {
        // List of lists to store all the combinations
        List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        // initially, sending in an empty list that will store the first combination
        csHelper(n, new ArrayList<Integer>(), ans);
        // a helper method to print list of lists
        print2dList(ans);
        return ans.size();
    }

    private void csHelper(int n, List<Integer> l, List<List<Integer>> ans) {
        // if there are no more stairs to climb, add the current combination to ans list
        if(n == 0) {
            ans.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(l));
        }

        // a necessary check that prevent user at (n-1)th stair to climb using 2 stairs
        if(n < 0) {
            return;
        } 

        int currStep = 0;
        // i varies from 1 to 2 as we have 2 choices i.e. to either climb using 1 or 2 steps
        for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            // climbing using step 1 when i = 1 and using 2 when i = 2
            currStep += 1;
            // adding current step to the arraylist(check parameter of this method)
            l.add(currStep);
            // make a recursive call with less number of stairs left to climb
            csHelper(n - currStep, l, ans);
            l.remove(l.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    private void print2dList(List<List<Integer>> ans) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < ans.get(i).size(); j++) { 
                System.out.print(ans.get(i).get(j) + " "); 
            } 
            System.out.println(); 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test2 t = new Test2();
        t.climbStairs(3);
    }
}
```

Please note this solution will timeout for larger inputs as this isn't a memoized recursive solution and can throw MLE(as I create a new list when a combination is found).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone looking for a python solution, for this problem.

```
def way_to_climb(n, path=None, val=None):
    path = [] if path is None else path
    
    val = [] if val is None else val
    if n==0:
       val.append(path)
    elif n==1:
        new_path = path.copy()
        new_path.append(1)
        way_to_climb(n-1, new_path, val)
        
    elif n>1:
        new_path1 = path.copy()
        new_path1.append(1)
        
        way_to_climb(n-1, new_path1, val)
        
        new_path2 = path.copy()
        new_path2.append(2)
        
        way_to_climb(n-2, new_path2, val)
    return val
```

Note: it is based on the @unlut solution, here OP has used a top-down recursive approach. This solution is for all people who looking for all combination of staircase problem in python, no python question for this so i have added a python solution here

if we use a bottom-up approach and use memorization, then we can solve the problem faster.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you did find the correct answer to the problem with your code, you can still improve upon it by using just one if to check if the steps left is 0. I used a switch to check the amount of steps taken because there are only 3 options, 0, 1, or 2. I also renamed the variables that were used to make the code more understandable to anyone seeing it for the first time, as it is quite confusing if you are just using one letter variable names. Even with all these changes the codes run the same, I just thought it might be better to add some of these things for others who might view this question in the future.

```
public static void climbStairsHelper(String pathStr, int stepsTaken, int stepsLeft)
{
    if(stepsLeft == 0)
    {
        switch(stepsTaken)
        {
            case 2:
                System.out.print(pathStr.substring(0, pathStr.length() - 2) + "]");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.print(pathStr + "");
                break;
            case 0:
                System.out.print("");
                break;
        }
    }
    else if(stepsLeft == 1)
    {
        System.out.print(pathStr + "1]");
    }
    else 
    {
        climbStairsHelper(pathStr + "1, ", 1, stepsLeft - 1);
        System.out.println();
        climbStairsHelper(pathStr + "2, ", 2, stepsLeft - 2);
    }

}`
```

`