# Recursion - Stairs Problem - Why doesn't my code work? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Problem:

In this problem, the scenario we are evaluating is the following: You're standing at the base of a staircase and are heading to
the top. A small stride will move up one stair, and a large stride advances two. You want to count the number of ways to
climb the entire staircase based on different combinations of large and small strides. For example, a staircase of three steps
can be climbed in three different ways: three small strides, one small stride followed by one large stride, or one large
followed by one small.
Write a recursive method `waysToClimb` that takes a non-negative integer value representing a number of stairs and prints
each unique way to climb a staircase of that height, taking strides of one or two stairs at a time. Your method should output
each way to climb the stairs on its own line, using a 1 to indicate a small stride of 1 stair, and a 2 to indicate a large stride of
2 stairs. For example, the call of `waysToClimb(3)` should produce the following output:

```
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 1]
```

My Code:

```
def waysToClimb(n,a=[]):
    if n == 0:
        print(a)
    if n >= 1:
        a.append(1)
        waysToClimb(n-1,a)
    if n >= 2:
        a.append(2)
        waysToClimb(n-2,a)
```

But for example when I type:

`print(waysToClimb(3,[]))`

The result is `[2, 1] [2, 1, 1, 2] [2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]`. Why doesn't my code work correctly?

EDIT: I was supposed to change "a" variable within function not outside it. I wrote fct(n,a+[2]) instead of a.append(2) and it worked. Thanks for help all.

Comment: When you used a debugger, what is the *first* thing it did that was unexpected?  (Hint: It *never* gets to the last `if`.)

Comment: Well I understand it doesn't get to last if but why doesn't it? Isn't it supposed to continue to second if after completing the recursion in first if. The initial n is bigger than 1.

Comment: I'm not positive this is the source of your bug, but mutating the list *and* returning it seems like a recipe for confusion, as is the mutable default arg.  I would recommend building a new list in each call (combining the results of recursive calls as needed) and returning it rather than having all of them share a single reference that gets passed in as an arg.

Comment: Here's an example of how you might combine the recursive calls and return the result: `def waysToClimb(n): return [[]] if n == 0 else [[1]] if n == 1 else [[s] + ways for s in (1, 2) for ways in waysToClimb(n-s)]`

Comment: The first recursion has a `return` statement; you don't "continue" from a `return` statement (which a debugger would have made clear).

Comment: Oh okay I got that and edited the question but it still gives wrong answers

Answer (score 1):

Something, well, *differently* convoluted:

```
def ways2climb(n,sofar=[]):
    return [sofar] if n==0 else (ways2climb(n-2,sofar+[2]) if n>=2 else []) + ways2climb(n-1,sofar+[1])
```

Comment: After reading your code I got where I was wrong. I was supposed to change "a" variable within function not outside it. I wrote fct(n,a+[2]) instead of a.append(2) and it worked. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

[refer to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54608714/staircase-problem-how-to-print-the-combinations)

```
def way_to_climb(n, path=None, val=None):
path = [] if path is None else path

val = [] if val is None else val
if n==0:
   val.append(path)
elif n==1:
    new_path = path.copy()
    new_path.append(1)
    way_to_climb(n-1, new_path, val)
    
elif n>1:
    new_path1 = path.copy()
    new_path1.append(1)
    
    way_to_climb(n-1, new_path1, val)
    
    new_path2 = path.copy()
    new_path2.append(2)
    
    way_to_climb(n-2, new_path2, val)
return val
```

Scroll down the link mentioned and you will find the code i pasted here.

Already given by someone, this will help you out to figure out the correct answer.

Comment: This answer is given by @sahasrara62